# Error en query al crear unas tablas con llaves foraneas en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy esjecutando un query con C# y me sale el siguiente error..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el query que estoy ejecutando, en algo falla no se porque, aún no se bien sql...

```
      CREATE TABLE Empresa( id_empresa int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
                , nombre char(60) NOT NULL
                , giro char(50)
                , total_activos int NOT NULL
                , total_inactivos int NOT NULL
                )

      CREATE TABLE Usuario( id_usuario int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
                , nombre char(60) NOT NULL
                , password char(200) NOT NULL
                , estatus int NOT NULL
                , ult_fecha_acceso DATETIME
                , CONSTRAINT FK_Usuario_Empresa FOREIGN KEY (id_empresa) REFERENCES Empresa (id_empresa) 
                )

       CREATE TABLE Historial( id_historial int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
                  , inicio_sesion DATETIME NOT NULL
                  , cierre_sesion DATETIME
                  , CONSTRAINT FK_Historial_Usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES Usuario (id_usuario)
                  )

       CREATE TABLE DEF( id_def int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
            , placa_original char(15) NOT NULL
            , estatus int NOT NULL
            , motivo char(500)
            , placa_editada char(15) NOT NULL
            , fecha_hora DATETIME NOT NULL
            , CONSTRAINT FK_DEF_Usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES Usuario (id_usuario)
            )
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la query que estás ejecutando? ¿Qué datos tienes en las tablas que utilizas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te lanza ese error porque no has creado la columna que servirá como FK amigo.
Te dejo el código:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuario( id_usuario int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
                , nombre char(60) NOT NULL
                , password char(200) NOT NULL
                , estatus int NOT NULL
                , ult_fecha_acceso DATETIME,
                empresa_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Empresa(id_empresa)
                )
```

Debes aplicar lo mismo para las otras tablas.

Saludos!

Comment: No sabía eso, pensé que se generaba sólo... Gracias.